# Can't install php-fpm: dependency issues

Tags: php, nginx, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I'm trying to install php-fpm for my nginx server.
Trying to install through yum (`yum --enablerepo=remi install php-fpm php-mysql`), I get the next error:

```
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.24-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Linux version:
Linux version 2.6.18-028stab107.1 (*****@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46))

Thanks ahead

--EDIT--

When trying to use --skip-broken I got this error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0 from install of compat-mysql51-5.1.54-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16.0.0 from install of compat-mysql51-5.1.54-1.el6.remi.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.1.69-1.el6_4.x86_64
```

Trying to run `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` did not help.

--UPDATE: SOLVED--

So, I removed `--enablerepo=remi` from the command and it worked. If anyone could explain in the comments what `--enablerepo=remi` does, I'd be glad because the instructions I found online to set up a LAMP environment suggested this command to install php-fpm.

(sadly I can't answer my own question as I lack the reputation)

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions?

Comment: Now I have. gave me a different error, edited the question. Thanks